# Ansible module: ec2_elb unable to find ELB (when ELB count>400?)

Tags: boto, ansible, amazon-elb

I have EC2 instances that needs to be added to an ELB. While trying this from ansible, getting the following error. I am able to add the same using AWS CLI. Found this open issue with the module **ec2_elb** in ansible: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2115

Is there any work around for this? Or any other version of boto/python where this works as expected. I do have >400 ELB's in the profile that i am using.

> msg: ELB MyTestELB does not exist.

Comment: As a work around, trying to execute AWS CLI commands from within ansible play to get the instances added to ELB. Having some proxy issues which is resulting in timeouts etc. Will post an answer once it goes through that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Using AWS CLI command from ansible to get rid of above issue with boto/ansible not able to identify the ELB.

```
- name: Add EC2 instance to ELB {{ elb_result.elb.name }} using AWS - CLI from within ansible play
    command: "sudo -E aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name {{ elb_result.elb.name }} --instances i-456r3546 --profile <<MyProfileHereIfNeeded>>"
    environment:
      http_proxy: http://{{ proxyUserId }}:{{ proxyPwd }}@proxy.com:port
      https_proxy: http://{{ proxyUserId }}:{{ proxyPwd }}@proxy.com:port
```